# "Neither of the box of chocolates is suitable as a gift"

Tags: grammar

Is the use of *box* in this sentence correct?

> Neither of the **box** of chocolates is suitable as a gift.

Answer (score 12):

There are two ways to fix this sentence, it's slightly wrong. You can either say

> Neither box of chocolates is suitable as a gift.

or

> Neither of the boxes of chocolates is suitable as a gift.

Comment: "neither of the _boxen_ of chocolates..." surely  ;-)

Comment: @martinf only if the chocolates are GPL